# Shapes moving on an HTML5 canvas when they're not supposed to: requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: animation, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas, es6-class

I want to create many rectangles that start at the top of the html-canvas and start moving downwards until they disappear out of the view-box of the canvas. So I created a class with a lot of parameters (x-position, y-position, width, height, color, context) such that I can use a for loop to create many rectangle-objects with whatever arguments I want to pass to them. Problem is... *drum roll*

The shapes start moving downwards once I pass the function that creates the rectangle objects and animates them to the requestAnimationFrame method. heck, I didn't even tell them to move!

enough yada-yada, here's the code: (view the snippet in full-screen)

```js
function resize(canvasElement) {
    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        canvasElement.width = window.innerWidth / 3;
        canvasElement.height = window.innerHeight * 0.9975;
    })
}
var radius = 5;
class roundRect {
    constructor(rectX, rectY, rectHeight, rectWidth, stroke, fill, c) {
        c.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        c.beginPath();
        c.strokeStyle = stroke;
        c.fillStyle = fill;
        c.moveTo(rectX + rectWidth/2, rectY);
        c.arcTo(rectX + rectWidth, rectY, rectX + rectWidth, rectY + rectHeight, radius);
        c.arcTo(rectX + rectWidth, rectY + rectHeight, rectX, rectY + rectHeight, radius);
        c.arcTo(rectX, rectY + rectHeight, rectX, rectY, radius);
        c.arcTo(rectX, rectY, rectX + rectWidth / 2, rectY, radius);
        c.closePath();
        c.fill();
        c.stroke();
    }
}
function animate(rectYpar) {
    new roundRect(50, rectYpar, 100, 8, "red", "red", ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
{
    var canvas = document.body.querySelector("#canvasOne");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 3;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.9975;
    resize(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    animate(0)
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#canvasOne {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <canvas id="canvasOne"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**: For some reason the snippet does not run on stack-overflow, so here's a link to the page on codePen:

https://codepen.io/Undefined_Variable/pen/aaWNJV

view it in full-screen and refresh it every time the shape runs downwards to see the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, guys: I've found the problem: The animate function should have had the following structure:

```
var rectY = 10;
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    new roundRect(10, rectY, 50, 7, "blue", "red", ctx);
    rectY += 1;
}
```

and to draw a shape, the callback should have been like this:

```
animate();
```

Probably no one cares, but thanks anyway lol